# Inserting a value anywhere within a queue

Tags: c++, generics, data-structures, queue

I am writing a member function for a generic queue implementation using a linked list. The goal of the function is to insert a value anywhere within the queue.

In the 'else' case, I traverse the queue using a loop and update a pointer accordingly. When I arrive at the desired location, I save the 'next' location with another pointer and insert a new node that points to the previous 'next.' It seems that this is not logically sound and I am having trouble figuring out why. Is this just a syntax issue that I'm experiencing? I have included my implementation below.

```
template <typename T>
void queue<T>::insert_anywhere(const T& val, const int position){
    if (position == 0) {
        Node<T> *t1 = head;
        head = new Node<T>(val, t1);
        num_items++;
    } else {
        Node<T> *t2 = head;
        for(int i = 0; i <= position-1; i++){
           t2 = t2->next;
        }
        Node<T> *t3 = t2->next;
        t2->next = new Node<T>(val, t3);
        num_items++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error. When `position == 1`, you insert an element between second and third node. No value of `position` results in inserting between first and second.

Comment: Is it still a queue data structure if you can insert anywhere within the queue?

Comment: After running some tests, it seems that the code only fails when `position == 0` but works if the position is set to any value less than the size. Also, to your point Thomas, I agree it's confusing but apparently its called an 'unfair queue.'

Comment: *After running some tests, it seems that the code only fails when position == 0* -- If you have all of this information, it's time to use the debugger.

Comment: It would cease to be a queue, and just be a list. You're attempting to wrap a linked list with another list.